# Firestore rules for not existing documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Below code works if I have collection (in this case suppliers)

```js
function isNotRestrictedinSuppliers(){
  let value=3;
  let suppliers=get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/settings/suppliers);
  return suppliers.data.suppliers_array.size() < value;
  //return true;
}
 match /suppliers/{document=**}{        
    allow read,update, delete: if isSignedIn() && isValidUser();
    //above is the same like allow write;
    allow create: if isSignedIn() && isValidUser() && (isPremium() || isNotRestrictedinSuppliers());  
}
match /suppliers/{supplier}{        
    allow read,update, delete: if isSignedIn() && isValidUser();
    //above is the same like allow write;
    allow create: if isSignedIn() && isValidUser() && (isPremium() || isNotRestrictedinSuppliers());  
}
```

Unfortunately, if there is no collection "suppliers" it doesn't work.
What I want to do is restrict creation of suppliers but create if no supplier exists

Comment: Which rule is failing here? The one for suppliers document or any nested document? Also, can you please share the code the you are running that should pass these rules?

Comment: The code is OK if documents (in this case "supplier") exist, but it doesn't work if there are no documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Security Rules won't allow users to create if/else conditions. So basically you need to create another function to check if supplier documents exist and return true if it doesn't exist

```
function notExists(){
  let suppliers=exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/settings/suppliers);
  return !suppliers
}
```

> This would cost one additional read per security check

Comment: I think this is my solution. But I think I won't use it:) I changed mind and I create sample data with 1 document for every user. I try to make rules simply

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to read a collection in sercurity rules. This is what document says:

> The get() and exists() functions both expect fully specified document paths.

But you can [count documents with aggregation queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries) via client sdk.

Comment: I know document path. When a user creates a document, it creates the path. The document doesn't exist only on beginning